# Unable to insert data into MySQL table via ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio

I have installed MySQL on my local computer and am trying to enable insertion of data to a created MySQL table from my ASP.NET web application on Visual Studio 2017. I've managed to set up a MySQL connection successfully and created table called 'events'.

Initially, I do not have any syntax or system errors, using the code below, but whenever I try to insert data from my web form upon clicking, no data is inserted into the MySQL table. Any advice if there is anything wrong in my code or any other file configurations?

Later, after I tried installing Connector for .NET, I still cannot insert data into the MySql and I get the below errors in namespace MySqlConnection stating 'the-type-mysqlconnection-exists-in-both-mysql-data-issue' as seen below

Any advice what can be corrected to be able to insert data into my table? Is it in my Insert code or does problem lie elsewhere? Below are my code:

AddEvent.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Prototype3
{
   public partial class AddEvent : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
     //convert event date input into DateTime format on back-end of page 
     string dateStr = dateinput1.Value;
     DateTime date;

     //Saving data on added event into MySQL database
     string constring = "server=localhost;user id=***********; 
     password=***********!; 
     persistsecurityinfo=True;database=homesecretary";

      //Connection to database below-check!!
      string Query = "INSERT into events (eventTitle) VALUES 
      ('"+tb_eventTitle.Text+"')"; //Parse date input from jQuery 
      datepicker 
      MySqlConnection connDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring); 

      MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, connDataBase);
      MySqlDataReader myReader;

      try
         {
             connDataBase.Open();
             myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
             connDataBase.Close();
         }
```

Web.config:

```
  <configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
   <add name="homesecretaryConnectionString" 
   connectionString="server=localhost;user 
   id=********; password=********; persistsecurityinfo=True; 
   database=homesecretary" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
   .....
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Note that the [tag:visual-studio] tag description says *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."* Please [edit] your question to remove it.

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection and SqlCommand are both IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Then you won't need to explicitly Close it, since exiting the block calls Dispose which calls Close. Avoid string concatenation to construct queries or the code becomes vulnerable to SQL injection attacks: use SQL parameters.

Comment: And although you have put your connection string in config, the code doesn't use it, it just duplicates it - add a reference to `System.Configuration` and use [ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a very basic/fundamental mistake here.

The [MySqlDataReader](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader.htm) purpose is to use when we are selecting data. You need to insert data not query so it should be calling `ExecuteNonQuery()` method:

```
// for inserts/updates queries
cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Please refer to the following docs for seeing an example on how to insert data in ADO.NET:

[MSDN - Insert New Records in to Database](http://Insert%20new%20records%20into%20a%20database)

**Note:** Please don't do string concatenation for creating queries as it is not a good practice instead of that you should be using Parameterized queries. [See an example here](https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/ado-net/insert-records-using-simple-and-parameterized-query-c-sql.php)

Answer (score 0):

To `update/insert` the data you may need to use `ExecuteNonQuery` and to fill the `DataSet` you may use `MySqlDataAdapter` as follow:

```
private static string _DBConnectionString = string.Empty;    
public static int SetData(string sqlQuery)
{
    int iReturn = -1;
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery);
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(DBConnectionString))
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Open();

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            iReturn = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        iReturn = -1;

    }
    return iReturn;
}

public static object GetData(string sqlQuery)
{
    DataSet dtSet = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery);
        MySqlDataAdapter adpt = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(DBConnectionString))
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Open();

            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            adpt.SelectCommand = cmd;

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            adpt.Fill(dtSet);


            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {   

    }
    return dtSet;
}
```